Is there a library that can be used to test multiple techniques of tcp/udp holepunching?
I have tried to punch a hole using netcat in udp mode and couldn't make it work, i also tried libp2p circuit-relay technique to no avail, i also experimented with bittorrent holepunching in the past and it didn't work.
I then discovered pystun3 and when i run it in the peers i control, i get "Full Cone" as the nat type of both my peers, which should in theory be the easiest NAT type to punch a hole in but i didn't had much success doing it.
Is there a library that can be used to traverse the NAT(punch a hole) between 2 peers?
the library should contain multiple techniques to test to find which technique works best for these peers, I do have access to a public peers which i can use as a signaling server if it is need.
the library can be in about any language, go,c,c++,python,javascript ...etc
